# Next week day for a given vector of dates

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to get the next week day for a vector of dates in R. My approach was to create a vector of weekdays and then find the date to the weekend date I have. The problem is that for Saturday and some holidays (which are a lot in my country) i end up getting the previous week day which doesn't work.

This is an example of my problem:

```
vecDates = as.Date(c("2011-01-11","2011-01-12","2011-01-13","2011-01-14","2011-01-17","2011-01-18",
                      "2011-01-19","2011-01-20","2011-01-21","2011-01-24")) 
testDates = as.Date(c("2011-01-22","2011-01-23"))


findInterval(testDates,vecDates)
```

for both dates the correct answer should be 10 which is "2011-01-24" but I get 9. 
I though of a solution where I remove all the previous dates to the date i'm analyzing, and then use `findInterval`. It works but it is not vectorized and therefore kind of slow which does not work for my actual purpose.

Comment: You might want to look into the package `bizdays` which identifies business days.

Comment: @iod I all ready have a vector of business days. that's no the problem. What i'm having problem is moving the dates to the next business day

Comment: `findInterval` gives you the index of the element before your x (i.e., the number of interval) e.g.: `x<-c(1,5,6,8); findInterval(7,x)` gives you 3 (i.e., the interval between 6 and 8). If you want the index of the element at the end of your interval, just add 1 to the result of `findInterval`.

Comment: (similarly, if you give a date before your first date, the result will be 0)

Comment: @iod Thats exactly what I need it (also understanding `findInterval`) and its what i'm using it. Someone just copy and made it an answer. Thanks any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
 vecDates = as.Date(c("2011-01-11","2011-01-12",
                     "2011-01-13","2011-01-14",
                     "2011-01-17","2011-01-18",
                     "2011-01-19","2011-01-20",
                     "2011-01-21","2011-01-24")) 
testDates = as.Date(c("2011-01-20","2011-01-22","2011-01-23"))

get_next_biz_day <- function(testdays, bizdays){
   o <- findInterval(testdays, bizdays) + 1
   bizdays[o]
}

get_next_biz_day(testDates, vecDates)
#[1] "2011-01-21" "2011-01-24" "2011-01-24"
```

Comment: @almost pefect, but i just moves every date 1 day. But in your example "2011-01-20" should not be move because it has an exact match in vecDates. I manage to solve that issue.